# Very different compression rate with two similar files

Tags: compression, zip, winrar

I'm using WinRar to compress two text files, of approximately the same dimensions (80Mb), which contain a Json structured text.

The text is generated by the same program and, inspecting it, it seems there is no apparent difference in the structure between the two files (Json fields are the same, only values vary).

Yet, when compressing them into a Zip file, there is a 1:10 mismatch in the compression rate. Namely, one file gets compressed into approx. 2Mb and the other one into approx. 20Mb.

What could be the reason for such a large mismatch?

Comment: Post the two files and you may get an answer.

Comment: OK, I made a smaller version of the files (the mismatch in the compression ratio still holds). I also uploaded the zipped archive:
[Files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/zrw7d6fr0ru7956,4c9ksvt1l8hiwdc,lcjgjxlepzlakuz/shared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have duplicated your results.

It seems that the data in the file `Ticker_May.txt`
does does not lend itself to the default level of compression,
[DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE),
which is oriented for speed rather than best compression.

Compression works by detecting repeating patterns in the data, so is dependent on
factors such as the size of the buffer used for examining segments of data.
Most compressing products use parameters to dictate the quality of the
compression, where usually better compression requires more CPU.

Zipping while using the Compression level of "Ultra" resolved the problem,
so the size of the Zip archive for `Ticker_May.txt` became even 29% smaller than
that of the zipped `Ticker_April.txt`.

I remark that the compression of your files by 7Zip was about twice smaller than
Zip, even when the Zip was done at the "Ultra" compression level.
7Zip uses a much better compression algorithm/format than the antique one used
by Zip.

Comment: Interesting finding! I checked in WinRar,however, and could not find the option "Ultra". Maximum compression is "Better", and using that option the compression ratio doesn't change much. Are you referring to 7Zip there as well?
I should analyze the files in details to try to understand how the pattern changed (is this possible in the first place?). And then understand why this happened all of a sudden, using the same generating program.

Comment: I was using another software - 7Zip, which does have an Ultra setting for Zip. Just a question of the parameters made available by the software you use.